# Issue with for loop in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Initially the array holds the default values as 100. Once if the enemy looses its health then i want to set the default values from 100 to 0. When all the array elements gets a value of 0 then the message will trace as game win.

```
var enemyHealth:Array = new Array(100,100,100,100,0);

    for (var i = 0; i< enemyHealth.length; i++)
    {

        if (enemyHealth[i] == 0)
        {
            trace ("game win");
        }

    }
```

Actually the issue is if any one of the array element holds a value of 0 then it trace a massage as game win.

So can any one help me in this regard.

Comment: do you want an if statement for checking when ALL the elements are 0?

Comment: Yes mr sharma. like (0,0,0,0,0); //output game win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all elements, not just one:

```
var allZero:Boolean = true;
var enemyHealth:Array = new Array(100,100,100,100,0);

for (var i = 0; i< enemyHealth.length; i++)
{

    if (enemyHealth[i] != 0)
    {
        allZero = false;
        break; // We know it's not a win, so we can stop the loop early
    }

}
if (allZero) {
    trace ("game win");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr dasblinkenlight its worth for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
var enemyHealth:Array = new Array(100,100,100,100,0);

var isDead:Boolean = true;
for (var i = 0; i< enemyHealth.length; i++)
{

   if (enemyHealth[i] != 0)
   {
        isDead = false;
        break;
   }
}

if(isDead)
{
    trace ("Game Win");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what the other answerers have said or something like this which might help you more to get the exact amount of enemies dead.

```
var enemyHealth:Array = new Array(100,100,100,100,0);
var enemiesDead:int=0;

    for (var i = 0; i< enemyHealth.length; i++)
    {

        if (enemyHealth[i] == 0)
        {
            enemiesDead++;
        }

    }

if(enemiesDead==enemyHealth.length)
{
    trace("Game Over");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `every` method to check that every element of your array (or vector) meet a criterion.

```
const enemyHealth:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[100,100,100,100,0];

const zeroHealth:Function = function(item:uint, index:int, vector:Vector.<uint>):Boolean {
   return item === 0;
}

if (enemyHealth.every(zeroHealth)) {
    trace("Game win")
}
```

I have changed the `array` to a `Vector` because they are more efficient, and you can specify the type of the elements, but it also works fine with `array`.